# How can i make this c++ code work?

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

This c++ code giving me errors and I dont know how to remove those errors.
**code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
string& RaiseItToUpperCase(string& w)
{
int len = w.length();
for (int index =0; index <len; index++)
    w[index]= toupper(w[index]);
return w;
}
void LoadData()
{
string filename;
while(true)
{

    cout<<"Enter Data file:";
    cin>>filename;
    cout<<"Filename entered"<<filename<<endl;
    ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());
    if(!myfile.good())
    {

        cout<<"Please Enter a Valid text File"<<endl;
        continue;
    }
    static std::string const targetExtension ("txt");
    if (!(filename.size() >= targetExtension.size() 
    && std::equal (filename.end() - targetExtension.size(),
    filename.end(),
    targetExtension.begin() ) ))
    {
        cout<<"File is not txt"<<endl;
        continue; 
    }
    break;
}
string i = filename;
string o;
cout<<"Enter an output file name:"<< endl;
cin>>o;
ofstream output;
ifstream input(filename);
output.open(o.c_str());
int charc =0;
int numw =0;
int longl =0;
int shortl =10000;
while (input>>1)
{
    numw++;
    charc = charc + i.length() +1;
    if (i.length() > longl)
    {
        longl = i.length();
    }
    if (i.length() < shortl)
    {
        i =RaiseItToUpperCase(i);
        output << i;
        if(input.get() ==32)
        {
            output<<" ";
        }
        else
        {
            output<<"\n";
        }
    }
    charc = charc - 1;
    output<<"\nWord Counter Summary\n"<<endl;
    output<<"Total Number of Words:"<<numw<<endl;
    output<<"Total Number of Characters:"<<charc<<endl;
    output<<" Largest Word Size:"<<longl<<endl;
    output<<" Smallest Word Size"<<shortl<<endl;
}
}
int main ()
{
LoadData();
return 0;
}
```

This is c++ file stream program and I am trying to run this code but it giving me errors and  i am not able to figure out how remove this errors
**so Can anyone tell me how to remove those errors and make this code run**

**Update**

here is the Error:

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)   c:\users\acer\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\consoleapplication15\consoleapplication15\sour‌​ce.cpp  52  1   ConsoleA‌​pplication15

And thanks in advance

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: Error 1 error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\users\acer\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication15\consoleapplication15\source.cpp 52 1 ConsoleApplication15

Comment: and other errors too

Comment: `while (input >> 1)` you're trying to put what's in `input` into the number `1`

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do in `while (input>>1)` ? 
If you want read out something:

- If you want to read to an integer like `int8_t` (or `int16_t` / `int32_t` etc.):

  `int8_t number = 0;
  while (input >> number)`
- If you want to read to a `char`:

  `char ch;
  while (input >> ch)`